# Animating changes in a SliverList

Tags: flutter

I currently have a `SliverList` whose items are loaded dynamically. The issue is that once these items are loaded, the `SliverList` updates without animating the changes, making the transition between loading & loaded *very* jarring.

I see that `AnimatedList` exists but it isn't a sliver so I can't place it directly in a `CustomScrollView`.

Comment: Franklin, did you end up finding a solution for this? I have a similar situation and haven't found discussion or examples of animations or transitions between slivers within a CustomScrollView.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your reply, unfortunately I never found a solution for this.

Comment: Any luck in 2019?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably know about this now, but might as well mention it here to help people.

You can use [SliverAnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverAnimatedList-class.html). It achieves the required result.

**SliverAnimatedList Construction:**

`itemBuilder` defines the way new items are built. The builder should typically return a `Transition` widget, or any widget that would use the `animation` parameter.

```
SliverAnimatedList(
     key: someKey,
     initialItemCount: itemCount,
     itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) => SizeTransition(
              sizeFactor: animation,
              child: SomeWidget()
     )
)
```

**Adding/removing dynamically**

You do that by using `insertItem` and `removeItem` methods of `SliverAnimatedListState`. You access the state by either:

1. providing a `Key` to the `SliverAnimatedList` and use `key.currentState`
2. using `SliverAnimatedList.of(context)` static method.

In cases where you need to make changes from outside of the list, you're always going to need to use the key.

Here's a full example to clarify things. Items are added by tapping the `FloatingActionButton` and are removed by tapping the item itself. I used both the `key` and `of(context)` ways to access the `SliverAnimatedListState`.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliverAnimatedListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SliverAnimatedListTestState createState() => _SliverAnimatedListTestState();
}

class _SliverAnimatedListTestState extends State<SliverAnimatedListTest> {
  int itemCount = 2;

  // The key to be used when accessing SliverAnimatedListState
  final GlobalKey<SliverAnimatedListState> _listKey =
      GlobalKey<SliverAnimatedListState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Sliver Animated List Test")),

      // fab will handle inserting a new item at the last index of the list.
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _listKey.currentState.insertItem(itemCount);
          itemCount++;
        },
      ),


      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAnimatedList(
              key: _listKey,
              initialItemCount: itemCount,

              // Return a widget that is wrapped with a transition
              itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) => 
                 SizeTransition(
                    sizeFactor: animation,
                    child: SomeWidget(
                        index: index,

                        // Handle removing an item using of(context) static method.
                        // Returned widget should also utilize the [animation] param
                        onPressed: () {
                          SliverAnimatedList.of(context).removeItem(
                              index,
                              (context, animation) => SizeTransition(
                                  sizeFactor: animation,
                                  child: SomeWidget(
                                    index: index,
                                  )));

                          itemCount--;
                        }),
                  ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  final Function() onPressed;

  const SomeWidget({Key key, this.index, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text("item $index"), 
              onPressed: onPressed,
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: You should explain this instead of just providing a link. Answers with just a link are often frowned upon :)

Comment: @MBorg I edited as you suggested (Thank you). It's funny that the answer above me was not frowned upon though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Implicitly Animated Reorderable List](https://pub.dev/packages/implicitly_animated_reorderable_list)

```dart
import 'package:implicitly_animated_reorderable_list/implicitly_animated_reorderable_list.dart';
import 'package:implicitly_animated_reorderable_list/transitions.dart';
...

SliverImplicitlyAnimatedList<Comment>(
  items: comments,
  areItemsTheSame: (a, b) => a.id == b.id,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Comment item, int index) {
    return SizeFadeTransition(
      sizeFraction: 0.7,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animation: animation,
      child: CommentSliver(
        comment: item,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for using a simple ListView with a Sliver. It's not perfect and it has limitations, but it works for the case where you just have 2 Slivers, the AppBar and a SliverList.

```
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (_, _a) => SliverAppBar(<Insert Code Here>),
  body: MediaQuery.removePadding(
    removeTop: true, 
    context: context, 
    child: AnimatedList(
      <InsertCodeHere>
    )))
```

You can tweak around with the Widget tree, but that's the basic idea. Wrap the sliver appbar in a NestedScrollView and place the List in the body.

Answer (score 1):

You could Wrap your list items in an AnimatedWidget

Read about it in the docs [AnimatedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedListState-class.html)