# How to animate elements in a Flutter SliverList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver, flutter-animatedlist

I have a `SliverList` which I use with a `SliverAppBar` to animate the app bar when the user scrolls the list (standard use case of slivers really, nothing fancy).

Now I'd like to add animations to the elements in the `SliverList`. Like for instance horizontal slide transitions when items are added, or a kind of a vertical "shuffle" between elements when the list is reordered. The `AnimatedList` offers some of these features, but not the SliverList.

My understanding of the Framework is that it would probably be possible to wrap the elements provided to the `SliverList` within an `AnimatedWidget` (or some similar widget) to animate the changes. However my knowledge of Flutter animations is still a bit too fresh, so I'm asking for help.

Here's part of my code. I'd like to animate the `GameScoreWidget` instances below.

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return ListReorderWidget(viewModel: viewModel);
    }
    else if (!viewModel.isLatestGame(index-1)) {
      return GameScoreWidget(position: index-1, viewModel: viewModel);
    }
    else
      return Dismissible(
        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
        child: GameScoreWidget(position: index-1, viewModel: viewModel),
        key: UniqueKey(),
        background: Container(color: Colors.red),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          onGameDismissed(context);
        },
      );
  },
  childCount: viewModel.games.length+1,
  ),
)
```

I could'nt find any relevant answer to my problem. I found this question that's related [Animating changes in a SliverList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906505/animating-changes-in-a-sliverlist)

But no answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_animated

This package gives you `LiveSliverList()` which can be used to animate a sliverList easily